Continuity of a function defined implicitly via level sets
Let $X$ be a topological space and let $F:X\times[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be continuous. Suppose that for each fixed $x\in X$, the map $f_x:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ given by $f_x(t):=F(x,t)$ is monotone and assumes the value $\frac{1}{2}\in[0.1]$.
We may now consider, for each fixed $x\in X$, the least value of $t$ such that $f_x(t)=\frac{1}{2}$ and denote this value of $t$ by $m_x$. Similarly, the greatest value of $t$ such that $f_x(t)=\frac{1}{2}$ will be denoted by $M_x$. Hence  $f_x(t)=\frac{1}{2}$ if and only if $m_x\leq t\leq M_x$.

Are the maps $x\mapsto m_x$ and $x\mapsto M_x$ continuous?

In the case where $m_x=M_x$ holds for all $x$, the proof follows from the fact that the graph of $F$ is closed (in the triple-product space). I tried the same strategy and showed that the set $K:=\left\{(x,t)\in X\times[0,1]\,:\,m_x\leq t\leq M_x\right\}$ is closed, but I don't see how one can show that the 'lower boundary' $\left\{(x,t)\in X\times[0,1]\,:\,t=m_x\right\}$ is closed, too.

The statement is not true, and I think you'll be able to find a counterexample yourself, once you focus on doing that. My approach would be to define$X$ and $F$ in a way that $m_x=M_x$ for every $x$ except for one $x_0$ which is not an isolated point.

@Stefan What if we assume that $X$ is compact and Hausdorff? I'm actually treating the case when $X$ is the $n$-sphere.

This counterexample is motivated by @Stefan’s comment and takes the OP’s comment about $X$ into account.
Let $X= S^1$ which can be thought of as $[-1,1]$ with endpoints identified. Let me also use $[-1,1]$ instead of $[0,1]$ for the other sets, and $0$ instead of $\frac12$ for the special point. Consider the continuous function $F:X\times[-1,1]\to[-1,1]$ given by
$$
F(x,t) = |x| t.
$$
For each $x$, it is clear that $f_x$ is monotone because $|x|$ is nonnegative. Moreover, for $x\ne0$, we have $m_x =M_x = 0$, whereas for $x=0$, we have $m_x = -1$ and $M_x = 1$. Therefore, the maps $x\mapsto m_x$ and $x\mapsto M_x$ aren’t continuous.

What a lovely counterexample. Thank you!
